# Атрибут elevation не работает

Tags: java, android, material-design

Здравствуйте!

Решил написать приложение с использованием Material Design, начал работать с тенями. Но атрибут `android:elevation` не работает (хочу "поднять" `Toolbar`). Как заставить его работать? Пробовал искать - большинство сетуют на прозрачность, однако что бы я с ней не делал, тень не появляется. Также обращу внимание на то, что я использую библиотеку...

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

...чтобы приложение нормально работало на устройствах с Android 4. Тестирую на устройствах с `4.1.2` и `4.2`, пока нет возможности запустить на `5.0`. Разметка приложения:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/Activity_Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="10dp" /> ← Не работает
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/Activity_FC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Activity_PTC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694192/3212712) пишут ([и в доках тоже](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float))) что работает сие свойство только для 5-ого андроида.

По первой ссылке [предлагают](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747592/3212712) пользовать стили свои фоны и т.д., пока в support либы не добавят обратную совместимость.